# Adding apache.commons.net to RCP TargetPlatform

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, target-platform

I am developing an Eclipse 4 RCP application and I am using apache.commons.net library for my project, but when i try to add it as dependency from my manifest file, application doesn't find it and says

Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.commons.net; bundle-version="3.2.0"

When I search the library at the Run configuration-> Plug-in, I see that plug-in doesn't exist, nevertheless how I can add apache.commons.net plug-in to my RCP application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start developing an eclipse rcp application the available plugins you can use are resolved by your current eclipse ide. You can use all plugins that are in the plugins folder of your eclipse. To be independent from your ide you can create a target file. How to do this and use it is explained in the following tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html

In this target platform file you can add the eclipse orbit repository which contains the bundle org.apache.commons.net in the version 3.2.0. The Url for the newest repository is:

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20170818183741/repository